# Why using logarithmic scale for time series forecasting?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

Recently, I built some models (LSTM, XGBOOST, etc) for time series forecasting. I've tested those models in synthetic and real data. In some obscure forum, I've read that it would be better to transform my data into a logarithmic scale. I've done this transformation and my models performed much better.

However, I'm not sure about the reason underlying this improvement.
Why using a logarithmic scale is better for time series forecasting? This improvement is a general fact or does it depend on my data?

Comment: Without more details, it is impossible to answer. For some data, the transformation would make sense, for some not. If your data contains negative values, the transformation is not even possible.

Comment: If typical events are percentage growth or decline and the levels are less important (though always positive) then logarithmic analysis may be meaningful

Comment: It is a data-dependent problem. In fact, taking logarithm could smooth out skewness (to some extent) and hence easier for prediction.